# Custom Profile Provider : The settings property '' was not found - MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been having this issue when trying to edit/update a user profile. Essentially when a user registers, they have a bool call 'AuthorizedTeamMember' set to false. Their Team Manager can then set it to true to authorize the user.

However, when clicking the "Authorize" button to authorize the user I get the following error:

```
The settings property 'AuthorizedTeamMember' was not found.
```

I've had a good look around to find a solution, but nothing seems to work. It seem's to error before it hits the method 'AuthorizePlayer' on the HttpPost.

**Anyway here's my custom profile provider:**

```
namespace iConfirm.Models
{
    public class TeamPlayer : ProfileBase
    {
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public virtual string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", value);
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public virtual string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetPropertyValue("LastName", value);
            }
        }
        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        public virtual string DateOfBirth 
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.GetPropertyValue("DateOfBirth").ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetPropertyValue("DateOfBirth", value);
            }
        }
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public virtual string PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.GetPropertyValue("PhoneNumber").ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetPropertyValue("PhoneNumber", value);
            }
        }
        public virtual string TeamId
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.GetPropertyValue("TeamId").ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetPropertyValue("TeamId", value);
            }
        }
        public virtual bool AuthorizedTeamMember
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)base["AuthorizedTeamMember"]; //<-- Errors here on post
            }
            set
            {
                base["AuthorizedTeamMember"] = value;
            }
        }
        public static TeamPlayer GetProfile(string username)
        {
            return Create(username) as TeamPlayer;
        }

        public static List<TeamPlayer> GetProfilesByTeam(int teamId)
        {
            //var profileList = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
            var profilesInTeam = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
            .Select(user => TeamPlayer.Create(user.UserName, true) as TeamPlayer)
            .Where(profile => profile.GetPropertyValue("TeamId").ToString().Equals(teamId.ToString()))
            .ToList();

            return profilesInTeam;

        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the code that will Authorize the user:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AuthorizePlayer(TeamPlayer teamPlayer)
        {
            teamPlayer.AuthorizedTeamMember = true;
            var user = TeamPlayer.GetProfile(teamPlayer.UserName);
                user.FirstName = teamPlayer.FirstName; 
                user.LastName = teamPlayer.LastName;
                user.AuthorizedTeamMember = teamPlayer.AuthorizedTeamMember;
                user.DateOfBirth = teamPlayer.DateOfBirth;
                user.PhoneNumber = teamPlayer.PhoneNumber;
                user.Save();
            /*TeamPlayer _teamPlayer = TeamPlayer.Create(teamPlayer.UserName) as TeamPlayer;
            //var tempProfile = TeamPlayer.Create(teamPlayer.UserName) as TeamPlayer;
            _teamPlayer.AuthorizedTeamMember = true;
            _teamPlayer.Save();
            //Email user that they have been authorized*/
            return View("Index");
        }
```

**And finally the view:**

```
@model iConfirm.Models.TeamPlayer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AuthorizePlayer";
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Model.UserName);
}

<h2>AuthorizePlayer</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Authorize the following user?</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuthorizedTeamMember)
        <div class="display-label">
            Username
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            Full Name
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            Email
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @user.Email
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            Telephone number
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            Date of Birth
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Authorize" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Might be missing something but is there a reason your using

this.SetPropertyValue()

for all the properties except for base["AuthorizedTeamMember"] = value;